# Problems contact between two SpriteNodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I have a problem with my `func` contact because the second contact don't work (contact with Bonus and Vaisseau) but the two others contact don't work.

So this is my code :

The function :

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        let PremierBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyA
        let SecondBody : SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB

        if ((PremierBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Meteorites) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Meteorites)) {
            contactEntreMeteorites(PremierBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Meteorites2: SecondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
        }
        else if ((PremierBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Bonus) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau) ||
            (PremierBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Bonus)){
                gameOver(PremierBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Vaisseau: SecondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
                print("CONTACT")
        }
        else if ((PremierBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Meteorites) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau) ||
        (PremierBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau) && (SecondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategories.Meteorites)){
        gameOver(PremierBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Vaisseau: SecondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
            print("Couco")
        }
    }
```

And this is my Physics categories :

```
struct PhysicsCategories {
    static let Meteorites : UInt32 = 1
    static let Bonus : UInt32 = 2
    static let Vaisseau : UInt32 = 5
}
```

This in my func DidMoveToView :

```
Vaisseau = SKSpriteNode(texture: Vaisseau1)
        Vaisseau.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
        Vaisseau.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Vaisseau.size)
        Vaisseau.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        Vaisseau.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau
        Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus
        Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Meteorites
        Vaisseau.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Vaisseau.setScale(0.08)
        self.addChild(Vaisseau)
```

And i create my `SpriteNode` Bonus in this function :

```
func ApparitionBonus() {

        let BonusSprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Bonus.png")
        var BonusApparitionX = UInt32(self.frame.size.width)
        var BonusApparitionY = UInt32(self.frame.size.height)

        BonusApparitionX = arc4random() % BonusApparitionX
        BonusApparitionY = arc4random() % BonusApparitionY

        BonusSprite.position = CGPointMake(CGFloat(BonusApparitionX),CGFloat(BonusApparitionY))
        BonusSprite.setScale(0.8)
        BonusSprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 20)
        BonusSprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        BonusSprite.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus
        BonusSprite.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Vaisseau
        BonusSprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.addChild(BonusSprite)

        let RotationBonus = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 3)
        let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(3)
        let actionFini = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        BonusSprite.runAction(SKAction.sequence([RotationBonus, wait, actionFini]))
        BonusSprite.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(RotationBonus))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `didMoveToView`, when you call:

```
Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus
Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Meteorites
```

You set the `contactTestBitMask` to one category, and then another.  You need to bitwise or them together.  Something like:

```
Vaisseau.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategories.Bonus | PhysicsCategories.Meteorites
```

This will combine the two bit masks, which will allow it to contact both the `Bonus` and `Meteorites`.

If you don't want your sprites to collide, set the `collisionBitMask` to `0x0` (or however you want to represent 0):

```
Vaisseau.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0x0
```

Comment: I have always the problem even with your advice

Comment: I found the solution.  I must change `BonusSprite.physicsBody?.dynamic = false` to `true`

Comment: @MathisDelaunay  Very interesting, that's not what I expected.  At least it is working now!

Comment: Yes but i don't understand why does dynamic change something :)

Comment: @MathisDelaunay  Neither do I.  Maybe a bug with Swift 2?  I'm pretty sure I've done this type of thing before in Objective-C, and it has worked.  Or maybe there is something where the two non-dynamic objects will not collide?  Is there a problem with setting it dynamic?

Comment: yes i have some others problems with dynamics because now , my Vaisseau can be moved my other sprite node who touch him :/

Comment: @MathisDelaunay Okay, it appears that two non-dynamic objects cannot collide (same goes for some of the `SKPhysicsBody` constructors).  See my edit for how to make sure that your `Vaisseau` can use `collisionBitMask` to not collide.